# ConstantForce and RigidBody

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, gravity, gameobject, rigid-bodies

Im quite new to programming and working with the coding system in Unity.  I have searched the web for this but I still haven't found a solution or proper answer.

Could ConstantForce affect a GameObject without a RigidBody?

I am wanting to create a magnetic like effect on my GameObject so that it is pushed backwards like a strong wind on an incline while I am trying to move forward.  I tried to use a RigidBody but the gravity of the RigidBody makes the GameObject slide down the incline.  Because of this effect I haven't started scripting the movement because I dont want the gameObject to start sliding backwards when forward motion stops.  I want this to be done by the ConstantForce.

Thank you in advance for any answers and I hope I was able to explain this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the RigidBody to be able to apply [**ConstantForce**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConstantForce.html).

> Constant Force is a quick utility for adding constant forces to a
>   Rigidbody. This works great for one shot objects like rockets, if you
>   don’t want it to start with a large velocity but instead accelerate.

You can disable the gravity on a RigidBody to solve your problem.

```
if(collider.attachedRigidbody)
   collider.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = false;
```

Comment: Does this only work in 3D or can i use it in 2D as well?